# Apply Pantone color from Pantone Connect in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pantone

So I installed the Extension from the Pantone Color Mafia

[image]

Now I want to Apply that color to the black rectangle.
But when I hit the Color Swath, nothing is happening.

How do I make the black rectangle become Pantone 374 U ?

Comment: Is that the trial version?  Or are you paying the subscription?

Comment: I pay for the subscription but am still in the trial period of the first 30 days

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from paying for this, but I have a basic (free) account where I can login online and search for a pantone colour. I just sample the RGB colour from their website, and then add it as a new spot colour swatch in whatever software I'm using, and rename it.. It's just one more step to sample the colour, and so I don't think the plugin is worth the money TBH, at least not for me.  You can then just tell your printer to use a Pantone colour guide book to match spot colour during printing. They should be doing this anyway since it's standard practice.

Comment: You can copy the .acb files from an older InDesign version to the proper folder in the current version and thereby get the Pantone color books back. They won't be updated anymore of course.

Comment: @BillyKerr I wasn't sure if printers accept this workaround. count me in.

Comment: It doesn't matter to a printer. RGB/CMYK values are not used for printing spot colours. Printers use the physical Pantone spot colour guides.  They will mix the inks according to formula on the Pantone spot colour guide, and match the colours to the guide during printing. It's standard practice.  I worked in offset lithography for for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Right-click on the three dots on the upper right of the color
2. Select "Add to swatch". Then it will Appear in InDesign

The pen tool cursor doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Now it is in the regular color palette of InDesign.

The Choice "+ Add to Palette" is wrong. It adds the color to a palette within Pantone Connect and not InDesign. Seems useless and confusing.

There: Nice!

[image]